# Visual Studio compiles with CMake in x64-Debug mode but in x64-Release mode "could not find any instance of Visual Studio"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm using `Visual Studio` to open a `CMake` C++ project. When I set it to `x64-Debug` mode at the top and compile, it works fine. However, when I change it to `x64-Release`, it suddenly tells me:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:5 (project):
Generator
Visual Studio 16 2019
could not find any instance of Visual Studio.
```

I'm literally using `Visual Studio`, why does `CMake` not find it anymore when building in release mode? I know that this code base compiled perfectly fine before and I didn't make any changes to it since then. Also, I tried to repair/reinstall `Visual Studio` but the issue persists. Can I verify some environment variables or whatever `CMake` checks?

When running `CMake` from `CMD` directly to generate a `Visual Studio` solution (`cmake -G "Visual Studio 16 2019"`), I get the same error as above. Running from `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"` or `Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022` does not help either.

`Desktop development with C++` and `C++ CMake tools for Windows` are both installed.

```
>cmake --version
cmake version 3.24.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that deleting all `Visual Studio` generated files/folders and setting up a new `x64-Release` configuration solved the problem.